# How to plot 5 largest values obtained by dividing one column by another with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
variety|points|price  
a      |  80  |  5  
b      |  85  |  6  
b      |  70  |  8
```

and so on.

I would like to create a barplot using seaborn that has variety on the x-axis and points/price ratio on the y-axis. I have about 150k rows, so I only want to display  the 5 best points/price ratios.

This was my idea using another column called result:

```
df["Result"] = df["points"]/df["price"]
ax = sns.barplot(x="variety", data=df, order=df["Result"].iloc[:5].index)
```

which does not work.

I will be glad for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to  filter out the first 5 largest values using **nlargest**.

```
largest_five= df.nlargest(5,'Result')
```

Then plot it

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="variety",y='Result', data=largest_five)
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks. But the number of values does not correspond to the length of "largest_five". For df.nlargest(5,'Result') it shows 3 bars. df.nlargest(8,'Result') shows 5 bars as I wanted. Is this normal behaviour? Is there a way to specify number of bars?